# SQL Server stored procedure error: Declare Table variable required

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

But although at my eyes seems all OK, I get an error when try to execute:

> Declare table variable "@_Tbl"

Code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_setSettings
(
    @UID nvarchar(50),
    @Tbl nvarchar(30),
    @Fld nvarchar(30),
    @Vle nvarchar (200),
    @WFld nvarchar (30),
    @WVle nvarchar (200)
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @S nvarchar(max)='',
            @P nvarchar(max)='',
            @W nvarchar(max)=''

    IF @Tbl <> 'Users' 
       SET @W = ' AND @_WFld=@_WVle'

    SET @S = 'UPDATE @_Tbl SET @_Fld = @_Vle WHERE UID=@_UID' + @W

    --print @S
    SET @P = '@_UID nvarchar(50),
              @_Tbl nvarchar(30),
              @_Fld nvarchar(30),
              @_Vle nvarchar(200),
              @_WFld nvarchar(30),
              @_WVle nvarchar(200)'

    EXEC sp_executesql @S,@P,@UID,@Tbl,@Fld,@Vle,@WFld,@WVle

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Can someone suggest what's wrong?

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with your dynamic sql but I have a question. Why do you need dynamic sql here? Your code is also wide open to sql injection.

Comment: `@_Tbl` is a variable of `nvarchar(30)` type, you cannot issue an update statement for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With All the fixes and sql-injection free

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_setSettings
(
    @UID    nvarchar(50),
    @Tbl    SYSNAME,
    @Fld    SYSNAME,
    @Vle    nvarchar(200),
    @WFld   SYSNAME,
    @WVle   nvarchar (200)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @S nvarchar(max), @P nvarchar(max);

 SET @S = N' UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@Tbl) 
        + N'  SET ' + QUOTENAME(@Fld) + N'  = @_Vle  '
        + N' WHERE UID = @_UID  '
        + CASE WHEN (@Tbl <> 'Users') 
          THEN N' AND ' + QUOTENAME(@WFld) + N' = @_WVle' 
           ELSE N' ' END

    --print @S
    SET @P = N'@_UID nvarchar(50),
               @_Vle nvarchar(200),
               @_WVle nvarchar(200)'

    EXEC sp_executesql @S
                      ,@P
                      ,@_UID = @UID
                      ,@_Vle = @Vle
                      ,@_WVle = @WVle

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

Comment: You just beat me to it. I was about to post nearly the same thing. :)

Comment: OK.. thanks .. I'll rewrite all the sp :-(
but.. what was the main issue concering sqlinjection?
not using QuoteName or the missing SYSNAME in Declarations

Comment: The main issue was Table name was being passed to dynamic sql as a variable, and dynamic sql treats it as a literal string rather than an object name. Using QUOTENAME function put sqaure brackets `[]` around the variable name and forces dynamic sql to treat it as an object name, these square brackets also protect you against sql-injection as it forces any value passed to variable to be treated as an object name and not a sql command.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use variables in the table name part of the update
i would do something like

```
SELECT @OBJ_ID = OBJECT_ID
FROM SYS.tables
 WHERE name =  @Tbl
```

to validate if the table exists 
and then insert it into the `@s`  like

```
 SET @S = 'UPDATE '+@Tbl+' SET @_Fld = @_Vle WHERE UID=@_UID' + @W
```